# Is it a good idea to use a message queue as websocket server in production (instead of Java EE @ServerEndpoint)?

Tags: websocket, message-queue

Is it a good idea to use a message queue as websocket server in production (instead of Java EE @ServerEndpoint)?

It would establish a loose coupling towards the JS client and perhaps reduce the load from the application, but are there major disadvantages? Should one really expose a MQ over the web?

Comment: There is far too little context here to know what you're doing, at what scale and with what overall requirements to even offer an opinion about whether this is an appropriate architectural direction or not.

Comment: Hm. I don't think so. The question is under which conditions it is a good idea to use a mq technology to deliver websocket messages to a JS client. Eg.: Is it better scalable? Isn't it slower? Would you use an mq for a priductive system with - say - several thousand or more concurrent users? Then: Why would you do so? Thank you.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't use an MQ without a really good reason that one was required and you've described nothing that says one is required or even useful for the task at hand.  So, if you just want a generic answer, then "no" you don't need an MQ just to send webSocket messages to javascript clients.  Not enough information here for me to respond further.  Good luck.

Comment: I think you are already on the way to answer my question. You say "...good reason that one was required". What would be requirements to make a mq necessary or helpful? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can send messages to websocket clients from within a java web application without the help of a message queue. And this is a good enough solution as long as you do not need the additional features that message queues have to offer (QoS 1/2, Retained messages, Last Will and Testament, ... for some more benefits of using a mq see for example: http://www.hivemq.com/mqtt-over-websockets-with-hivemq/)